# How to check which two variables are more correlated to variable "Price"?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Data Frame with 24 columns. I have to show the correlation among all the variables graphically. And I have to find the two most correlated variables to the variable "Price". I got the way a show this Data Frame as a graph:

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the correlation:

df4 = df_csv.corr()

# Show the graph:

sn.heatmap(df4, annot=True) 
plt.show()
```

But due to the graph being so busy with values and I can not check which two variables are more correlated to "Price" at a glance. How can I get some kind of filter to check easier the two most correlated variables to "Price"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are almost there. You have all the values in your df4. Select the column of interest, sort the values and select the first three rows:

```
df4["col_of_interest"].sort_values(key=abs, ascending=False).head(3)
```

As mentioned by Mustafa Aydin in the comments this approach assumes that strongest correlation is independent of the sign. Otherwise remove the `key=abs` part.

Comment: you are absolutely right with all your comments, thanks for that. I adjusted my answer. regarding the `key=abs` it depends on what the actual question is but I think this makes sense here

Comment: Really appreciate your help! But I did my degree in Economics many years ago and I don't remember why I should take the absolute vale of a correlation. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Maria you shouldn't take the absolute value of a correlation, sign matters there! in the code, it is used temporarily while sorting only. at the end, the raw values are presented. Example: r(price, var_1) = -0.84, r(price, var_2) = 0.73. If you don't use absolute value in sorting, then the -0.84 one is seen as very low and discarded. But actually it's important: it's very linerly correlated with the target, yet *negatively*, i.e., price tends to go down when var_1 goes up (and vice versa). Making the sort sign-independent allows that -0.84 to be not lost (and in fact place higher than 0.73).